# Body is not being send to status callback URL

Tags: flask, twilio

Using Flask and Twilio, I´m trying to receive user's message sent to a Twilio WhtsApp number. I´m using WhatsApp Sandbox. The problem is, the message sent by the user to the Twilio phone number is not being send to the callback URL. In order to illustrate this problem, this is **app.py**:

```
@app.route("/chatbot/receive", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def reply_whatsapp():
    print(request.values)
    print(request.form.get('body'))
```

This is **the output**:

```
>>> CombinedMultiDict([ImmutableMultiDict([]), ImmutableMultiDict([('SmsSid', 'SMaaaaa...'), ('SmsStatus', 'read'), ('MessageStatus', 'read'), ('ChannelToAddress', '+592XXXXXXXXX'), ('To', 'whatsapp:+592XXXXXXXXX'), ('ChannelPrefix', 'whatsapp'), ('MessageSid', 'SMaaaaa...'), ('AccountSid', 'ACssssssssssss...'), ('From', 'whatsapp:+14155238886'), ('ApiVersion', '2010-04-01'), ('ChannelInstallSid', 'WhatsAppChannelInstalled')])])
```

```
>>> None
```

**Notes:**

I´m using a free account

I'm using ngrok to handle the callback URL

Note Sandbox configuration says "status callback URL", so my idea is this web hook is not sending body in purpose

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're mixing two different callbacks here. There is a **Status Callback** and **A Message comes in** callback.

The purpose of the [status callback](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008989454-Tracking-the-Delivery-Status-of-an-Outbound-Twilio-SMS-or-MMS-Message) to track the delivery status of an outbound Twilio message.

> You currently use the `chatbot/receive` URL (renaming this endpoint might be a good idea as it suggests a different purpose)

The other callback is for responding [to incoming messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/sms-webhooks). This is what you are looking for and these requests contain a `body` parameter.

> You currently use the `demo-reply` endpoint for this.